# python script to pass txt file to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I need to pass the text line per line in a .txt file to a column from a table that got 4 columns, all empty, in a database.

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('prueback.db')
c = conn.cursor()


num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('subgenres.txt'))
f=open('subgenres.txt')
lines=f.readlines()
i=1
while True:
    subgenrename = (lines[i])
    c.execute("INSERT INTO subgenero (subgenrename) VALUES (?)", (subgenrename,))
    conn.commit()
    i+=1
    if i == num_lines:
        break


conn.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: That's an... interesting... way to read your file. See [how to read a file line-by-line into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) for more idiomatic python approaches. You might also read up on `executemany()` in the python sqlite3 bindings documentation.

Comment: @dmigo it runs but doesn´t make changes to the database

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pretty naive way of doing it, but have you try `pandas`? Pandas might add a little bit of overhead, but it's definitely useful for this kind of tasks, and it's not particularly slow for sqlite (another story with PostgreSQL).

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('prueback.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Don't know which type of file you have. I'm assuming a fixed width column text
data = pd.read_fwf('subgenres.txt') 

# This will create the table, or add rows if exists (just change the if_exists option to "append")
data.to_sql('subgenero', conn, if_exists='replace')

conn.close()
```

Now, if you have another table in you database you can pull the data from the database using Pandas:

```
table_db = pd.read_sql("select * from table", con=conn)

# In case they have identifiers (or if they keep the same row order)
table_db['subgenero'] = table_db.merge(suborder, on='id' ,how='inner')

table_db.to_sql('table', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

Check more information in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html)
and read with particular attention the `pd.to_sql` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html), there is a lot of options that might be particularly helpful depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you !!! It works, it create another table in the database with the info, is there a way to replace or add the information to an existing column in a table ?

Comment: Pandas is a data science library and not needed for this trivial task of text file read.

Comment: Sure @Parfait, it's a huge overhead, that's why I'm referring that as naive. Although, if the OP needs to add a column to a table it can easily be updated with `pandas` and avoiding the possible constrain problems when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `open` file using `with` context manager and iterate line by line. Never use `readlines` as it can be memory intensive since you read entire file at once.

```
with open('subgenres.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       c.execute("INSERT INTO subgenero (subgenrename) VALUES (?)", (line,))
       conn.commit()
```

Comment: It sent me an error NOT NULL constraint failed:, because I got 3 more columns in that table but i only want to fill that one.

Comment: Then you must have added a `NOT NULL` constraint in the `CREATE TABLE subgenero` call. This has nothing to do with Python code. Post output of `.schema subgenero` in SQLite CLI. Otherwise insert some non-NULL value in other required columns here.

Comment: Thanks it works, do you know how can i separate the text to another column ? For example:
I got a .txt file with: 
Rock also know as:  pop.
And i want to put the Rock in a column and pop in another. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think that's part of another question, and you can easily find related solved questions (N.B. That's why I recommended `pandas`).